# Java set location to WebView after loadContent to fetch relative links

Tags: android, webview, javafx, embedded-browser

I'm using WebView.getEngine().loadContent(String) to set content of an embedded Browser in my JavaFx Program but the HTML page has some relative links. which fails to load as the content is not linked to any location. Can any body help how to fix this issue?

Thanks.